# Check record length for fixed width files

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, gnu-coreutils

In a Unix environment, I occasionally have some fixed width files for which I'd like to check the record lengths. For each file I'd like to catch if any records  are not an appropriate line number for further investigation; appropriate size is known a priori.

If I want to check if all record lengths are the same, I simply run

```
zcat <gzipped file> | awk '{print length}' | sort -u
```

If there is more than one record length in the above command, then I run

```
zcat <gzipped file> | awk '{print length}' | nl -n rz -s "," > recordLenghts.csv
```

which stores a record length for row in the original file.

**What:** Is this an efficient method, or is there a better way of checking record length for a file?

**Why:** The reason I ask is that some of these files can be a few GB in size while gzipped. So this process can take a while.

Comment: You could do something with just awk without sorting and piping and all that: `awk -F, 'NF!=16{print "record: "NR" is length "NF}' infile.txt` where `16` is the number of expected fields in the record.

Comment: You can minimize the file I/O you are doing and only print the pair of lines if the lengths between the two differ, and you could test if a straight `read` may be quicker, e.g. `n=0; len=0; while read -r line; do [ "${#line}" -ne "$len" ] && echo "rec len varies at: %d\n" "$n"; ((n++)); len=${#line}; done < <(zcat <gzipped file>)`

Comment: @JNevill, my files are fixed width so number fields may not work since there is no field separator.

Comment: Fixed width is doable too using the `length()` function in awk: `awk 'length($0)!=16{print "record: "NR" is length "length($0)}' infile.txt`  `16` here is the character length instead of field count.

Comment: Other than tweaking around the edges, the biggest improvements will come by reading larger chunks of I/O at a time. It may be worth a small C program that reads/processes 1 Meg chunks at a time.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin While read loops are ridiculously slow...

Answer (score 1):

With pure awk:

```
zcat <gzipped file> | awk '{printf "%0.6d,%s\n", NR, length}' > recordLenghts.csv
```

This way you will save one extra subprocess.

Comment: I see, so you eliminated `nl` and move the line numbering to awk. This should help, thanks!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer please mark it as correct.